# Can I create pretrain model with tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, tensorflow

I takes a long time for train neural network model. It have to train every time when I run code. If I get high accuracy from training , Can I use same training model with another code without new training anymore ? How to do?

Comment: Sure you can! Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to train your model each time form the beginning. After training, you can store you model and next time you can load it, train it from that point or use it for your recall phase. You can find good tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) which have discussed storing and loading models in `Tensorflow`.